# firewall setup with secure and open actions in same controller

Tags: symfony, symfony-security, php-8.2

I have an API that I'm looking to switch to using symfony, the one big challenge I'm seeing so far is that the firewall is pretty strict, nearly every example has the assumption that I'll want to secure all of /api or all of /secure but I have a situation where a controller will be mixed.

For example, `/user/create` would be secured under an authentication token, but `/user/webhook` is a publicly available endpoint that doesn't require a token to access.

How would I make the firewall play well with this setup without resorting to changing a whole bunch of endpoints?

ideally symfony has an auth attribute I could tag to the actions that I wish to be secured so it's controlled like routing is.

I'm looking to use the latest version of symfony (which as of this post is 6.2)

Appreciate any sort of guidance on a solution.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#securing-controllers-and-other-code Just be careful when reading the docs about this sort of thing and ignore any references to the Sensio extra bundle.  It used to be used but has been replaced in Symfony 6.  Easy to get confused.  I might add that you can have as many controllers as you want including one controller per endpoint.  No limits there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify your `access_control` rules using regex in `security.yaml`. Order is important, so you need to specify rules from the most specific (path) to the less specific:

```yaml
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:

    # ...
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/user/create, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/user, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
```

In this case, the access `/user/create` the `ROLE_ADMIN` is required. Every other path starting with `/user` (like `/user/webhook`) will be public accessibly. You can add as many rules as you like (see https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#allowing-unsecured-access-i-e-anonymous-users).

To use another approach, useful if you want to manage security directly in your controllers, you can use specific methods and attributes: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#securing-controllers-and-other-code

Comment: managing it directly in the controller sounds more like what I'm aiming for. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

Using `access_control` is a blunt but effective way to control access for large portions of your site.

If you need something more fine-grained, you can declare required permissions per controller or per controller class.

For example:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Attribute\IsGranted;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    #[IsGranted('ROLE_USER')]
    public function index()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

See [Using Expressions in Security Access Controls](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/expressions.html) for more information.